# Why doesn't the field table in the Drupal database use entity_id as a primary key?

Tags: 7, views, database

I'm working on trying to optimize a View SQL query and I noticed that the query being executed is using a join on a the entity_id field of a field table. I noticed that for some reason unbeknownst to me the entity_id field is not a primary key. The delta field is a primary key.

Can anyone enlighten me as to why this is the case? Can I safely tag entity_id as a primary key without incurring a wrath of unintended consequences? Thank you for your help.

[image: field table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary key for a field table is compound, consisting of:

- entity_type
- deleted
- entity_id
- language
- delta

It's probably just the way your GUI is displaying the data that's confusing. This is Navicat's representation, for example:

[image]

If not, then something fishy has happened. Since the entity_id is supposed to be part of the compound key, if it *isn't*, it should be safe to add it to the rest. Take a backup first just in case.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look in another GUI or on the command line. For reference, I'm using Sequel Pro.

Comment: I have checked the table on the command line and I've confirmed that this is a GUI display issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The field tables store the usages of that field *for all entities* that use that field.  In other words, nodes and users could both have the same field on them.  In this case, a particular field could be on both nodes and users.  In this case, the entity ID may not be unique.